# Identify PII data using Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, cryptography, annotations

I want to identify PII fields of a class which are annotated with a custom annotation and then perform a encrypt/decrypt operation only on those fields and return the Class object .

Explaination:

1. Consider Class Employee .It has 3 fields .

   ```
       { 
        String name;
        String email;
        long phnNumber;
        }
   ```
2. Now I would write some custom annotation like @PIIData to identify which fields need encryption/decryption, and then annotate the fields with this annotation.

   ```
      { 
        @PIIData
        String name;
        @PIIData
        String email;
        long phnNumber;
        }
   ```
3. I now initialize object of Employee class with some values , and then pass this object to a encrypt/decrypt utility.

   **Pseudo Code :**

   ```
   Employee emp = new Employee('Alice','alice@al.com',999);
   utility.apply(emp);
   ```

**My Question :**

1. How can I make sure that when we pass any object to **utility.apply()** which has fields annotated with @PIIData, this utility should intercept that, perform encrypt/decrypt operation only on the annotated fields, and then return back same object to the caller?
2. Can I pass some value in the custom annotation so that we can explicitly tell utility to encrypt/decrypt ?

> eg @PIIData(value="Encrypt")

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java `Reflection API` to achieve the desired task. Assuming you have defined the Annotation `PIIData` yourself. Here's how you can implement the `apply` method. Also, define the `encryptValue` and `decryptValue` functions yourself.

Also, I am assuming your Employee class looks like this

```java
 class Employee {
    @PIIData(value = "Encrypt")
    String name;
    @PIIData(value="Decrypt")
    String email;
}
```

1. To intercept annotation first get all the fields defined by the `object` parameter in `apply` method using `Reflection API` then iterate through each field and check if it has some annotation using `isAnnotationPresent` function of `Reflection API` then you can check the value of the annotation and perform your code logic. You don't need to return back the object as `Reflection API` replaces the new value of the field in place.
2. To make sure the method works define some tests.
3. Yes you can pass values such as `Decrypt` and `Encrypt` to tell the `apply` method what to do.

```java
class Utility {
    static void apply(Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();


        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(PIIData.class)) {

                Object fieldValue = field.get(object);
                String annotationValue = field.getAnnotation(PIIData.class).value();

                if (annotationValue.equals("Encrypt")) {
                    // perform encryption
                    String encryptedValue = encryptValue((String) fieldValue);
                    // set the encryption through reflection API
                    field.set(object, encryptedValue);

                } else if (annotationValue.equals("Decrypt")) {
                    // perform decryption;
                    String decryptedValue = decryptValue((String) fieldValue);
                    // set the decrypted value
                    field.set(object, decryptedValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // define your encryption logic here
    static String encryptValue(String value) {
        return "encrypted:" + value;
    }


    // define your decryption logic here
    static String decryptValue(String value) {
        return "decrypted: " + value;
    }
}
```

Here's the test code for the above class methods

```java
public class UtilityTest {
    @Test
    void testApplyMethod() throws IllegalAccessException {
        Employee employee = new Employee("name", "email");
        Utility.apply(employee);
        assertEquals(employee.name, "encrypted:name");
        assertEquals(employee.email, "decrypted:email");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm also looking to encrypt & decrypt same value ? If we do @PIIData(Value="Encrypt") , it will only cater encryption ? Is there any way I can decide it during runtime ?

Comment: If you are using annotations then the value must be present at the compile-time. And yes if we do `@PIIData(value = "Encrypt")` then it will only cater to encryption. If you have used Hibernate or data-JPA you will get more sense from this. If you want to decide at runtime then I won't recommend the annotation approach. You can define a utility method and perform encrypt/decrypt on the `email` or `name` field and use `setter` to set the field at runtime. The annotation approach only gives you flexibility up to compile-time as the `value` that you provide is a compile-time constant.

Comment: Can we acheive this with your solution ? 
Eg : @Secure(value="Encrypt") private Address address; where class Address has 2 fields `String city` , `String postcode` ?